# How can I erase the redundant input?

Tags: c++

I am writing code to get 10 values to an array, get their average, and count the number of elements in the array larger than the average. My code is giving an error. It takes an extra input even though I didn't intend it. If the inputs are `1 2 3 4  5 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5`, the output should `5`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[5],i,*p,n;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        cin>>a[i];
    int sum=0;
    p=a;
    n=0;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        sum+=(*p+i);
    }
    int avg=sum/10;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        if((*p+i)>avg){
            n++;
        }
    }
    cout<<n<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int a[5]` --> `int a[10]`, otherwise you are indexing out of bounds.

Comment: You have an array of 5 elements but you read 10 numbers from the console into the array. You are overrunning the bounds of the array.

Comment: `sum+=(*p+i);` --> `sum+=p[i];`, `*` has higher precedence than `+` so you're just adding `i` to the first element of the array 10 times. You also don't even need `p` at all, just index `a`.

Comment: Given that you have a memory overwrite, the program from that point is basically useless.  Anything you've observed after that overwrite becomes a moot point.

Comment: Oh right! Silly mistake.

Comment: Your development environment most likely came with a debugger (and if it didn't, get a better development environment). With a debugger you can rung your program on your terms and watch what the program does as it does it. Keep an eye out for the unexpected. The unexpected is almost always a bug. Note that this means you have to know what is expected. If you don't, you can't debug code. Can't write anything that will work reliably, either.

Comment: Your program is a good example of why you should use `std::vector` instead of arrays.

Answer (score 2):

3 changes required:

1) Size of array should be 10.

2) Use the parenthesis correctly to access the value at memory location using pointers.

3) Use `double` for average.

Have a look at the following implementation:

```
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    int a[10],i,*p,n;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        std::cin>>a[i];
    int sum=0;
    p=a;
    n=0;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        sum += *(p+i);
    }

    double avg = (double)sum/(double)10;

    std::cout<<"Sum: "<<sum<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Average: "<<avg<<std::endl;

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(*(p+i)>avg){
            n++;
        }
    }
    std::cout<<"Count: "<<n<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Sum: 0
Average: 0
Count: 5
```

**PS:** Check out disadvantages of using namespace std.